# how to get the selected index of a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a normal dropdown which I want to get the currently selected index and put that in a variable. Jquery or javascript. Jquery perfered.

```
<select name="CCards">
<option value="0">Select Saved Payment Method:</option>
<option value="1846">test  xxxx1234</option>
<option value="1962">test2  xxxx3456</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`$("select[name='CCards'] option:selected")` should do the trick

See jQuery documentation for more detail: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

UPDATE:
if you need the *index* of the selected option, you need to use the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) jquery method:

```
$("select[name='CCards'] option:selected").index()
```

Comment: Calling `index()` is orders of magnitude more list-searching busy-work than just using standard DOM `selectedIndex` and no more readable. I'd stick with the plain DOM property here.

Comment: @bobince: I wouldn't use jQuery to solve this question either, but as the OP asked for a jQuery solution... :-)

Comment: This was the simplest and exactly what I was looking for. The second line works perfect i used it like var indx = $("select[name='CCards'] option:selected").index();

Answer (score 26):

This will get the index of the selected option on change:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    console.log($('option:selected',this).index()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="CCards">
<option value="0">Select Saved Payment Method:</option>
<option value="1846">test  xxxx1234</option>
<option value="1962">test2  xxxx3456</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 24):

If you are actually looking for the index number (and not the value) of the selected option then it would be

```
document.forms[0].elements["CCards"].selectedIndex 
/* You may need to change document.forms[0] to reference the correct form */
```

or using jQuery

```
$('select[name="CCards"]')[0].selectedIndex
```

Answer (score 15):

the actual index is available as a property of the select element.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('CCards');
alert(sel.selectedIndex);
```

you can use the index to get to the selection option, where you can pull the text and value.

```
var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
alert(opt.text);
alert(opt.value);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<select name="CCards" id="ccards">
    <option value="0">Select Saved Payment Method:</option>
    <option value="1846">test  xxxx1234</option>
    <option value="1962">test2  xxxx3456</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /** Jquery **/
    var selectedValue = $('#ccards').val();

    //** Regular Javascript **/
    var selectedValue2 = document.getElementById('ccards').value;


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) for `<select>` elements

e.g.,

```
document.querySelector('select option:checked')
document.querySelector('select option:checked').getAttribute('value')
```

You don't even have to get the index and then reference the element by its sibling index.